# Can an independent clause be interrupted by a conjunction without a comma and still be an independent clause?

Tags: grammar, clauses, independent-clauses, compound-sentences

Can an independent clause be interrupted by a conjunction without a comma and still be an independent clause? e.g.:

He poured me another drink and I drank it.
or:
Max climbed onto his horse and we rode away.

Would these be considered compound sentences? Or are these sentences grammatically incorrect?

**As far as I know, compound sentences must include a comma. Is this information incorrect?**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is a compound sentence. A clause has a subject and a verb, and can stand on its own, and since both clauses can stand by themselves, they are both independent clauses.

https://grammar.yourdictionary.com/grammar-rules-and-tips/independent-and-dependent-clauses.html states the differences between independent and dependent clauses.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Did you want to address the comma question?

Answer (score 0):

You have two independent clauses joined by a coordinating conjunction (a compound sentence) whether you use a comma or not. Independent clauses don’t much care about punctuation, but stylists tend to:

> When independent clauses are joined by *and*, *but*, *or*, *so*,
> *yet*, or any other coordinating conjunction, a comma usually precedes the conjunction. If the clauses are very short and closely connected,
> the comma may be omitted . . . unless the clauses are part of a
> series. These recommendations apply equally to imperative sentences .
> . .
>  <sub>Source: [*The Chicago Manual of
> Style*](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org) (login required)</sub>

Here are a couple of the offered examples:

> *All watches display the time, and some of them do so accurately.*
>  but
> *Electra played the guitar and Tambora sang.*

Comment: Some prescriptivists might insist on a comma in CMOS’s second example sentence. However, even they usually don’t object when both clauses share a modifier, e.g.: “At the party, Electra played the guitar and Tambora sang.”